Relation between four-components of the Dirac wavefunction and the four solutions of the Dirac equation
Recently I've been studying the Dirac equation. I've studied that the Dirac wavefunction must have four components ($4\times 1$ column matrix) since the Dirac Hamiltonian must be a $4\times4$ matrix to satisfy the Klein-Gordon equation. Then I studied that the Dirac equation has four solutions, each represent a spin-up and spin-down fermions, and spin-up and spin-down antifermions. But each solution of them is yet another $4\times 1$ column matrix. So I reasonably think of the Dirac wavefunction as a superposition of these four solutions to the Dirac equation. But does the four-components of the Dirac wavefunction has something to do with the four solutions of Dirac equation? Does it mean that if the Dirac wavefunction was a $2\times 1$ column matrix, then the Dirac equation can only have two solutions?

A four-dimensional space needs four vectors to span it.
